# How to insert a char to a vector of strings

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring

Isn't this the correct way to insert a character into a vector of strings?

The compiler returns `-1073741819` when I run it.

Following is the code, in which I want to add more chars next to `'A'` later.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <string> instruction;

    instruction[0].push_back( 'A' );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And once you fix the build error you have to consider the possibility of your program crashing, as you index the vector *out of bounds*.

Comment: a `char` is not a `std::string`. Why do you want to do that? Do you want to push a string of length 1 ?

Comment: `instruction` is a vector of strings.  `instruction[0]` is the first string in the vector. You want to add strings to the vector, not to another string.

Comment: Adding the <string> library didn't change anything.Also, @Ripi2, instruction[0] is the first string of the vector and I want to add a character to that string.

Comment: OK, the `push_back` method is well used. But... add to the vector first a string to which append a character!!!

Comment: Oh yeah you are correct. But is there a way to add a character to an empty vector of strings?

Comment: @Fureeish, Nope. I think you mean `instruction.push_back("A")`, with no [0] thing.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I glanced at the question and immediately saw `'A'` and completely overlooked the incorrectly used `operator[]`.

Comment: But that won't work because I will then add more chars next to A.

Comment: Hi John, one option that can be done to push a char to a vector of string is converting char value to string `instruction.push_back( to_string('A') )`

Comment: Once you have a first string, then `instruction[0].push_back(anotherchar)` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you declared a vector with template type as `std::string` you can not insert `char` to it, instead you can only have a string inside.

If you want to have a single character string as vector element, do simply:

```
std::vector <std::string> instruction;
// instruction.reserve(/*some memory, if you know already the no. of strings*/);
instruction.push_back("A");
```

Regarding your usage of [std::vector::operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at): that is wrong, because, it returns the reference to the element at the index you requested. The moment when you use it(in your code), there is no element available and hence it's usage leads you *[undefind behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)*

---

In the comments you mentioned that:

> I will then add more chars next to A

If you meant to concatenate characters to the vector elements(which is string type), you can either use [operator+=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) of string to add a new character to the **already existing string** element(s).

```
std::vector <std::string> instruction;

instruction.push_back("");  // create an empty string first
instruction[0] += 'A';      // add a character
instruction[0] += 'B';      // add another character
```

or simply `push_back` as you tried. But in the latter case also you need to have a string(empty or non-empty) element existing in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the first string into the vector at first to use the string object's method `push_back`.

```
int main()
{
    vector <string> instruction;

    instruction.push_back("");
    instruction[0].push_back('A');
    return 0;
}
```

But keep in mind that you can simply use `+=` operator of `string` class to get the same results:

```
instruction[0] += 'A';
```